Trouble understanding the proof of the theorem: If $f\in \mathfrak{a}$, then $m_i\in \mathfrak{a}$ for each $i$.
The following are from Froberg's Introduction to Grobner bases, Malik anad Sen's Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra
Background
Lemma:  Let $I$ be a momomial ideal and $f\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n]$.  Then the following are equivalent
$(i)$ $f\in I$.
$(ii)$ Every term of $f$ lies in $I$.
$(iii)$ $f=\sum_{\alpha=0}^{t} a_\alpha x^{\alpha}$ for some $a_\alpha \in K$ and $x^\alpha\in I, 0\leq \alpha \leq t$.
Note: In the proof of the above Lemmafrom the direction  $(i)$ to $(iii)$, the notations $h_i=\sum_{j=0}^{n_i} k_{ij} x^{\beta(ij)}, i=1,\ldots,q, k_{ij}\in K,\beta(ij)\in A,$ are used.
Theorem:  Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a monomial ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  Let $f=\sum c_im_i$, where $c_i\in k\setminus\{0\}$ and $m_i$ are different monomials. If $f\in \mathfrak{a}$, then $m_i\in \mathfrak{a}$ for each $i$,

Proof  We introduce the concept of fine grading or multigrading of the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  If $cm=c{x_1^{i_1}},\cdots,{x_n^{i_n}}, c_\in k\setminus\{0\}$, we set $\text{mdeg}(cm)(i_1,\ldots,i_n)$.  Let $\mathfrak{a}=\langle n_1,\ldots,n_s\rangle$ be a monomial ideal, and suppose $f=\sum c_im_i\in \mathfrak{a}$.  Then $f=g_1n_1+\cdots+g_sn_s$ for some $g_i=\sum c_{ij}m_{ij}\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  Let $c_im_i$ be a nonzero term in $f$.  Then $c_im_i$ equals the sum of all elements $c_{ij}m_{ij}n_i$ hich are of the same multidegree as $c_im_i$. Hence $c_im_i$ is a linear combination of the $n_i$'s, so $c_im_i\in \mathfrak{a}$.

Questions
For the proof of Theorem above, I am confused over the use of the index $j$ in the notation $c_{ij}m_{ij}$.  I understand when it says
...$f=\sum c_im_i\in \mathfrak{a}$.  Then $f=g_1n_1+\cdots+g_sn_s$ for some $g_i=\sum c_{ij}m_{ij}\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.
The authors mean:  $f=\sum c_im_i=g_1n_1+\cdots+g_sn_s=\sum c_{1j}m_{1j}n_1+\cdots+\sum c_{sj}m_{sj}n_s$.  But the $j$ in both $c_{1j},m_{1j}$ is in reference to what index notation, and how does it relate to $i$ in the sense does it depend on it?
Also if $cm=c{x_1^{i_1}},\cdots,{x_n^{i_n}}$, then how do $c_im_i$ and $c_{ij}m_{ij}$ both equal to $c{x_1^{i_1}},\cdots,{x_n^{i_n}}$?
Thank you in advance

Each $g_i$ is a sum of the form $\sum_{j=1}^{t_i} c_{ij}m_{ij}$, where $t_i$ depends on $i$. So $c_{ij} m_{ij}$ refers to the $j$-th term in the sum defining $g_i$. In the expression $\sum_j c_{1j}m_{1j}n_1+\cdots+\sum_j c_{sj}m_{sj}n_s$, each $j$ is specific to the sommation right before it ; if that bothers you, you can replace them by $j_1,...,j_s$ to have the indices be distinct symbols.

@FançoisGatine thank you for the clarification.  I really appreciate it.
